# Postgresql: transaction - exception procedure problem

Tags: postgresql, exception, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm trying to control a transaction with a procedure but I'm getting an error I cannot resolve.

This is the code:

```
drop table if exists cuentas;

create table cuentas (
    id serial,
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    saldo dec(15,2) not null,
    primary key(id),
    constraint saldo CHECK(saldo > 5000)
);


insert into cuentas(nombre, saldo)
values('Carlos',10000);

insert into cuentas(nombre, saldo)
values('Cesar',10000);

SELECT * FROM cuentas;

drop procedure if exists transferir;

create or replace procedure transferir(id_emisor int,id_receptor int,cantidad dec)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
-- adding the amount from the recievers's account 
update cuentas 
set saldo = saldo + cantidad 
where id = id_receptor;
-- substracting the amount to the sender's account
update cuentas 
set saldo = saldo - cantidad 
where id = id_emisor;
commit;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN check_violation THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Violación de saldo.';
        rollback;
        commit;
end;$$
```

When I try to execute:

```
call transferir(1,2,1000);
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  no se puede comprometer mientras hay una subtransacción activa
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL transferir(integer,integer,numeric) en la línea 13 en COMMIT
Estado SQL: 2D000
```

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76sbt.png)

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your Posgres version? (`select version();` will tell you). Did you turn on autocommit before calling the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Hi 'a_horse_with_no_name' and forum administrators,
Sorry for using this section which I know is not the correct place but I can't answer a_horse_with_no_name nor comment his suggestion.
I'm using Postgresql version 12.4.
Also I unselect autocommit.
But Postgresql throws the error.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, you could try to only use *one* account. If you had used the account you started the question with, you could have simply edited it and add the information you've been asked for...